# Master Public name, Internal name, etcd member pre-built DNS records doesn't resolve to Master external IP address on GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, kops, google-cloud-dns

I created a k8s cluster on GCE (Google Compute Engine) using **Kops**. After creating the cluster, ran `kops validate cluster` command which threw following error.

**unexpected error during validation: unable to resolve Kubernetes cluster API URL dns: lookup api.apic.gcpdemo.cloudtechexpert.net on x.x.x.x.254:53: no such host**

I looked at the DNS records in managed zone created using **Cloud DNS** service on GCP and noticed that all following records are pointing to some **random IP address** which I'm not even able to ping.

Do I need to manually ***point them to master IP address***? Is it a known issue?

**DNS Records**

- api.apic.gcpdemo.cloudtechexpert.net
- api.internal.apic.gcpdemo.cloudtechexpert.net
- etcd-a.internal.apic.gcpdemo.cloudtechexpert.net
- etcd-events-a.internal.apic.gcpdemo.cloudtechexpert.net

Comment: I don’t think you need to point it to the master IP address manually. Yes, there is a known networking issue going on within the GCP, can you confirm what GKE version are you using? So that I can confirm if it’s related to a known networking issue. 

Was it working fine before? When you first noticed this issue? Please specify the timestamp along with the time zone. Did you perform any upgrade or configuration changes after which you start to experience this issue?

Comment: @MuhammadEbaduddin, Thanks for your response. I'm using GCE (NOT GKE) to install the k8s cluster using Kops. This is the 1st time, I'm creating k8s cluster on GCE.